# Ngrx Store - Should all UI changes be in store?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material2, ngrx

I'm using Angular 2 with Ngrx and Angular Material.
Are all UI changes like dropdown or dialog supposed to be in store?

For example:

```
<button md-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<md-menu #menu="mdMenu">
  <button md-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button md-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</md-menu>
```

Should I support dropdown in the store?

Next example:

```
<md-sidenav-container class="example-container">
  <md-sidenav #sidenav class="example-sidenav">
    Jolly good!
  </md-sidenav>

  <div class="example-sidenav-content">
    <button type="button" md-button (click)="sidenav.open()">
      Open sidenav
    </button>
  </div>

</md-sidenav-container>
```

Can I use open method? Maybe I should create component that wrap sidenav in component that operate only on input `Input() open;`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For me, there are generally 3 questions I ask.

- Are the UI changes isolated to the component and do not affect other components?
- Do the UI changes need to be persisted when the view returned to after have been destroyed?
- For debugging purposes do you want to track this state (possibly in order to recreate the view of the end user?)

If you answered NO to these 3 questions then you probably do NOT need to put the state of that component in the store.

By not coupling something the store, you make it more modular, easier to test and reusable.

Comment: So Is it okay to keep some data in store and some part not?

Comment: the answer is always "It depends", but usually its ok. this is a good article on redux, but applies to store in general https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367

Comment: you can also think about that with time travelling. If you come back in time thanks to redux devtools, is your UI well displayed?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the store to keep state and the UI should be bound to that state. You can then keep Observable to that state hierarchy or subscribe to those state changes and update the UI accordingly and dynamically.

This is what I had in mind:

```
import {  Component } from "@angular/core";
    import { Store } from "@ngrx/store";
    // Other relevant imports ....



@Component({
  selector: 'some-comp',
  templateUrl: 'some-comp.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class SomeComponent implements OnDestroy {

employeeObs$:Observable<EmployeeInfo>;

constructor( private store: Store<IAppState>) {
this.employeeObs$ = this.store.select('employee')
.map((next: IEmployeeState) => next.info);
}

// ...
}
```

And then on html template something like:

```
<!-- Some other regular DOM 
...
...

-->

<!-- Conditional DOM based on state -->
<div *ngIf="employeeObs$ | async as employeeInfo">
    <div type="text">{{employeeInfo.name}}</div>
</div>

<!-- Some other regular DOM 
...
...

-->
```

The conditional tag will only show if Observable has data...

Comment: Can you justify it more solidly?